# Row number fetching

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

My table contains about 5000 rows. I want to know a particular row position in the table.
My stored procedure is:

```
 CREATE PROC Sp_getrownumber(@MemberID INT) 
AS 
    SELECT Row_number() 
             OVER (  ORDER BY joiningdate ASC) AS Rownumber, 
           M.memberid, 
           P.name, 
           M.joiningdate 
    FROM   tblmemberdata M 
           JOIN tblpersonaldetails P 
             ON M.memberid = P.memberid
```

But when I m trying 2 fetch a particular row, the row no is showing 1.
The code is :

```
 CREATE PROC Sp_getrownumber(@MemberID INT) 
AS 
    SELECT Row_number() 
             OVER (  ORDER BY joiningdate ASC) AS Rownumber, 
           M.memberid, 
           P.name, 
           M.joiningdate 
    FROM   tblmemberdata M 
           JOIN tblpersonaldetails P 
             ON M.memberid = P.memberid 
    WHERE  M.memberid = @MemberID
```

How to fetch the exact row number?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

modify it to:

```
alter proc SP_GetRowNumber
(@MemberID int)
as
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY JoiningDate ASC) AS Rownumber,
M.MemberID,P.Name,M.JoiningDate
FROM tblMemberData M join tblPersonalDetails P on M.MemberID=P.MemberID
) AS Counts
WHERE MemberID = @MemberID
```

Answer (score 2):

What you're seeing is because `ROW_NUMBER()` works on the local `SELECT` **only**, and not on the whole table!

Try this one:

```
CREATE PROC Sp_getrownumber(@MemberID INT) 
AS
    SELECT *
    FROM (
        SELECT Row_number() 
                 OVER (ORDER BY joiningdate ASC) AS Rownumber, 
               M.memberid, 
               P.name, 
               M.joiningdate 
        FROM   tblmemberdata M 
        JOIN tblpersonaldetails P 
               ON M.memberid = P.memberid
    ) tblRowCounter
    WHERE M.memberid = @MemberID;
```

What this code accomplishes is performing the filtering on an in-memory table which *retains* the original row numbers.

**However!** be aware that there **is no row numbering** in SQL. SQL just *knows* that there is a whole bunch of data belonging to a table. The `ORDER BY joiningdate ASC` statement inside of the `OVER` clause is **extremely important**! Changing that column, or adding more columns will potentially change the row numbers.

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE PROC Sp_getrownumber(@MemberID INT) 
AS 
    ;WITH Numbered AS (
      SELECT Row_number() 
               OVER (  ORDER BY joiningdate ASC) AS Rownumber, 
             M.memberid, 
             P.name, 
             M.joiningdate 
       FROM   tblmemberdata M 
           JOIN tblpersonaldetails P 
             ON M.memberid = P.memberid 
    )
    SELECT *
    FROM Numbered
    WHERE memberid = @MemberID
```